# Determine points of discontinuity and non-differentiabilty of the function $g(x)=\int_{-3}^3f(x-y)f(y)dy$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Define $$g(x)=\int_{-3}^3f(x-y)f(y)dy$$for all real $x$,where $$f(t)=\{
    \begin{array}\\
                1 & 0\leq t\leq1 \\
                0 & otherwise \\
    \end{array}
$$
At which points is $g(x)$ discontinuous and non-differentiable.

**My Attempt:**

$$g(x)=\int_{-3}^0f(x-y)f(y)dy+\int_{0}^1f(x-y)f(y)dy+\int_{1}^3f(x-y)f(y)dy$$

$$g(x)=0+\int_{0}^1f(x-y)f(y)dy+0$$

$$g(x)=\int_{0}^1f(x-y)f(y)dy$$

$$g(x)=\int_{0}^1f(x-y)dy$$

Put $x-y=t$

$$g(x)=\int_{x-1}^xf(t)dt$$

Not able to go further from here. I think we need to check at the points $x=0,1,2$

Comment: Not sure the ranges of $f(t)$ and the integral match up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(0,1)\cap (x-1,x)$ is an interval and $g(x)$ is the length of this interval. $g(x)=0$ if $x >2$ or $x <0$, $g(x)=x$ if $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $g(x)=2-x$ if $1\leq x \leq 2$. $g$ is continuous. I leave differentiability to you.